# Autosave input box's to database during pause in typing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autosave

I have a large form on my website that I want to be able to autosave to a database as the user is filling it out. Almost identical to how google drive works when typing a document.

I am trying not to have a function that runs every X seconds but rather a function that runs when the user has taken a break in typing. So, if the user has not typed in 1 hour but is still on the page, it doesn't keep pushing save requests.

This is all I have so far which is a basic javascript form submit.

```
$("#page1Form").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();  
  $changesSaved.text("Saving...");
  var url = "/backend/forms/page1-POST.php";
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: url,
         data: $("#page1Form").serialize(),
         success: function(data) { $changesSaved.text(data); }
        });
  return false;
  });
```

Comment: @MilchePatern fixed, sorry bout that

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Debounce the textarea change.

## Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/2LG8f/)

Put your ajax call in the `saveToDB()` function. These event names(`'input propertychange change'`) will trigger on any form element change such as radio buttons, inputs, etc.

```
var timeoutId;
$('#the-textarea').on('input propertychange change', function() {
    console.log('Textarea Change');

    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        // Runs 1 second (1000 ms) after the last change    
        saveToDB();
    }, 1000);
});

function saveToDB()
{
    console.log('Saving to the db');    
}
```

---

Here is a full demo showing you how to debounce a full form and use ajax to send the data and then return the status (Saving, Saved, etc).

## Demo full form and ajax: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/NxQ4A/)

Comment: I agree with you about the timeout, but your going to need to bind this to the entire form, not just a textarea.

Comment: This is awesome MLM, works exactly how I expected. Thanks for the suggestions @BlakePlumb I will definitely modify that.

Comment: @bryan Updated my answer with a solution for full form.

Comment: @MLM any chance you could give me an example of how to use the debounce?

Comment: @bryan Updated Answer. Check out the ajax demo

Comment: Thanks @MLM! What about if I also needed the save function to start on a change in radio button/check box?

Comment: @bryan Both demo's for full form are updated to accomdate radio and check boxes.

Comment: @MLM thanks for the great solution... I tried it though, and it appears to not be sending the data in the textarea.  It sends all the fields except the textarea.

Answer (score 7):

I know that this question is old, but I would like to include a code that I like the most. I found it here:
http://codetunnel.io/how-to-implement-autosave-in-your-web-app/

Here is the code:

```
var $status = $('#status'),
    $commentBox = $('#commentBox'),
    timeoutId;

$commentBox.keypress(function () {
    $status.attr('class', 'pending').text('changes pending');

    // If a timer was already started, clear it.
    if (timeoutId) clearTimeout(timeoutId);

    // Set timer that will save comment when it fires.
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        // Make ajax call to save data.
        $status.attr('class', 'saved').text('changes saved');
    }, 750);
});
```

It saves after the user stops writing for more than 750 milliseconds.

It also has a status letting the user know that the changes have been saved or not.

Comment: It doesn't work when the comment is selected+deleted or backspaced.

Comment: It works but I had to trigger the event based on both keypress and blur so that the last letter of the textarea is also saved : $commentBox.on('keyup blur', function () { .... }

Answer (score 1):

Try Sisyphus.js https://github.com/simsalabim/sisyphus. It persists the form data in the browser's local storage and is robust against tabs closing, browser crashes, etc...

Comment: This solution is not related to the question. Save to local Storage does not make Http request nor solved the issue of updating to a DB